How to do dependency injection with .NET OpenAI 2.1.0-beta.1?
Before, using Azure.AI.OpenAI 1.0.0-beta.xx,  I had this in my Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddAzureClients(x => { x.AddOpenAIClient( ...

This seems to have been deprecated. At least, I cannot find out how to set up dependency injection like that.
If I wanted to use OpenAIClient, should I just add a singleton? Is it thread-safe? I cannot find any mention of this. Something like this?
builder.Services.AddSingleton(new OpenAIClient(...

Now, how do I generate embeddings? The obvious way, if I already have an OpenAIClient, would be something like:
openAIClient.GetEmbeddingClient("123").GenerateEmbeddingsAsync(...

But that would create a new instance of EmbeddingClient each time. Could I have EmbeddingClient as a singleton then?
builder.Services.AddSingleton(services => services.GetService<OpenAIClient>().GetEmbeddingClient("123"));

Or is that not thread-safe to use?

You wouldn't be the first to comment on the (lack of) quality of Azure docs for .NET. Or even the code itself - most is auto-generated. The Azure OpenAI package depends on OpenAI's OpenAI package. That's where OpenAIClient come from. If you look at the AzureOpenAIClient source you'll see it's nothing but a factory class creating individual clients. GetEmbeddingClient returns a new AzureEmbeddingClient instance. You lose (or gain) nothing by making the class a singleton.

The problem is concurrency/threading, not memory usage. From both the AzureOpenAIClient and the OpenAIClient source it looks like the "thing" that probably can't be reused is the Pipeline. That in turn is part of Azure SDK's Client Model which says nothing about concurrency. There's a GH issue Add DI extensions for Azure and SCM-based clients

This is a reminder that the Azure SDK and .NET teams aren't the same. The Azure SDK is a work in progress and for whatever reason, they removed the service extension methods. I find the phrase Now that Microsoft.Extensions namespaces are considered part of the BCL unusual. In the GH issue PR, you'll see that the various clients are singleton. There's an issue complaining that  OpenAI options don't work well with DI because they use init properties but that's easy to work around in a factory method

Long story short - you should probably use factory methods to register individual clients created from AzureOpenAIClient as singletons, but keep an eye on them. A lot of ClientModel issues appear to be about Azure.OpenAI. Expect changes to the SDK at some point.

Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos ! These links help a lot.
